# RailsAdmin set default collection action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I've implemented a new collection action and declared it in the rails admin initializer:

```
config.actions do
  # root actions
  dashboard                 
  # collection actions
  scope_filter  #my custom action
  index                         
  new
  show
  edit
  delete
end
```

When navigating to a Model, the default action is always `index`, is there a way to override this and set the  `scope_filter` action as the default?

(rails_admin 0.6.2 with Rails 4.1)

[edit] As asked in the comments Here's an excerpt of the scope_filter plugin:

```
require 'rails_admin/config/actions/base'

module RailsAdminScopeFilter
  class RailsAdmin::Config::Model
    register_instance_option :scope_filter do
      nil
    end
  end

  class ScopeFilter < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
    RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)

    register_instance_option :collection do
      true
    end

    register_instance_option :http_methods do
      [:get, :post]
    end

    register_instance_option :visible? do
      current_model = ::RailsAdmin::Config.model(bindings[:abstract_model])
      authorized? && current_model.scope_filter
    end

    register_instance_option :controller do
      proc do
        if request.get?
          # GET, displaying data
          # Blablah
        else
          # POST, means that we want reorder stuff baby!
          # dosomethin else
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to put a redirect in your index action.

```
def Index
  redirect_to action: 'scope_filter'
end
```

Comment: That should do the trick. Where should I override the `index` action?

Comment: You would want to put that in the Index action for the model that you want to set scope_filter as the default for.

Comment: In the `rails_admin do ... end` block in the model? I don't have a `SuperModelController`, it's the index action of RailsAdmin :/

Comment: What controllers are you wanting to over ride the index for?  Do you mean the whole site index or just an index page for a controller?

Comment: This is not a controller I write myself, it's the index/list generated by [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/).

Comment: would it be possible for me to see your git?  Without seeing how you created your action scope_filter it is hard to find the best way to accomplish what your asking.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it is an app developed for a client. But I've edited the question to include an excerpt of my custom RailsAdmin plugin. I do not really see how it is relevant as we should probably look more into RailsAdmin configuration instead of the plugin...